# Search And Replace With Regex with header and tail

Tags: python, regex, search, replace, text-search

I'm new to regex and I want to search and replace every occurrence of a "variable".mean() with average("variable")

`m863991.mean()` to  `average(m463641)` or

`m863992.mean()` to `average(m463642)`

Where the beginning of the variable starts with m and ends with 1 or 2 with 5 digits in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re.sub` passing `lambda` for the replacement text. You can use the pattern `(.*?)\.mean\(\)`, and surround the captured group with parenthesis, and starting it with `average`

```py
>>> import re
>>> text='m863991.mean()'
>>> re.sub('(.*?)\.mean\(\)', lambda  x: 'average('+x.group(1)+')', text)
'average(m863991)'
```

But to be specific, as you have mentioned the criteria for these values, you can use the pattern `(m\d{5}[12])\.mean\(\)` for the values that start with `m`, 5 digits in the middle, and ending with 1 or 2, and `.mean()` at last.

```py
>>> re.sub('(m\d{5}[12])\.mean\(\)', lambda  x: 'average('+x.group(1)+')', text)
'average(m863991)'
```

Comment: Worked really well, as expected, exceptional skills, tx